# Отклонённая тревога спам/оскорбление всё равно работает как минус

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, тревоги, инструменты-модератора, кэширование

Обнаружил в изменении репутации странный момент:

[image: скриншот репутации]

Странность в том, что если я открываю [само сообщение](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257708/178988), то вижу голоса +1 -0:

[image: скриншот голосов]

Судя по всему дело в тревоге (имена заменены до создания скриншота, так что по длине не гадаем):

[image: скриншот тревоги]

В принципе, есть возможность явно почистить тревоги спам/оскорбление на сообщении, но я всегда считал, что отклонение так же отменяет и минус. Более того, сам голос ведь отменился, а уменьшение репутации осталось - как-то это совсем нелогично.

Может быть так задумано, но зачем? Мне скорее кажется ошибкой.

Comment: По-моему spam/r/a отклонение тревоги не отменяет минусов...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, ну рейтинг +1 -0 не соответствует репутации +10 -2, так что чую где-то косяк. Или должно быть +1 -1, или +10 -0.

Comment: Ну хз. Может просто репа не пересчиталась еще XD

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, сейчас +2 -0 и +10+10-2. Или думаешь, завтра пересчитается? Мне как-то кажется маловероятным, но подождать можно.

Comment: Черт его знает XD Я Ипатьеву тревогу r/a влепил, так ее отклонили а минус еще +- два дня висел. Кст зря отклонили, там реально уже выход за рамки правил.

Comment: Сейчас не видно никаких минусов в репутации

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, да, исправилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, на следующий день -2 всё-таки почистились:

[image: скриншот репутации]